# How best to commit build changes back to GIT branch in Jenkins during build

Tags: git, jenkins

Here's my current process:

1. I checkout a repo using the jenkins git plugin (no branching, just a checkout)
2. In the build steps  make multiple changes to source files, including sometimes creating new files
3. Run a exec shell build step `git add -A  && git commit -m "blahblahblah"`
4. In the post build steps, use git publisher to push changes back to origin

Step #3 doesn't seem right.  My hunch is the git plugin should have a way to run add/del/commit commands, but can't find a way in the build steps or the post build steps.

Am I doing this the only way possible?

Comment: git plugin is to read from a repo and publish to another repo, just that asaik. A part form this, your build process seems a but "esoteric" to me..:) Can I ask why you are doing all those manipulations just for a build?

Comment: What are you doing in your build process where you actually change code files? Why?

Comment: @vratojr our build process auto updates some files containing version info and such.  Also, we use jenkins to automate building of our site's sitemap files.

Comment: @jamesthollowell we use jenkins to automate a number of tasks you might not put in the official 'build' category, like automation of building our sitemaps.

Comment: Things like sitemaps, versioning, and the rest, are called artifacts, and the consensus is to keep them out of your source control.

Comment: @Denis I understand your point and agree 100% in general.  I don't claim my current need falls outside the general case either.  However, the question was not about general best practices of version control, but about functionality available for plugins for Jenkins.   If you know the plugins don't support what I'm looking for, the answer to my question could be 'They don't provide that functionality built in, because consensus views it as bad practice to commit artifacts during build or change code' if you know such functionality isn't implemented for those reasons.

Comment: Thank you for a suggestion for an answer. But I am unable to provide such assurance. I don't know. I just wanted to let you know, in case you weren't aware already, about the artifacts. You did know, which is great. Sorry to not be able to help you further.

Comment: Could you precise what you mean with "Step #3 doesn't seem right."? Editing the repository content sounds more like a build step than a post-build one, especially in a "publisher". Git publisher is able to push tags or branches. Making it perform commits sounds strange to me.

Comment: @JulienCarsique  I meant, within the Build Steps, not the Post build steps, be able to 'add a build step' like: 'commit changes to local branch'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the chain of comments and my own searching, doing it in an explicit exec shell build step seems to be the only valid way.